# Find the pole(s) and its/their order for the function $f(z) = \frac{z}{1-\exp(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have so far that:

$$\frac{z}{1-\exp(z)} = \frac{z}{z\left(1+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{6}+\dots\right)} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{6}+\dots}$$

But the bottom is not something I recognize.  It is similar to something but not exactly and I feel like maybe I'm overthinking this and the pole should simply be $0$ for obvious reasons (i.e. that $\exp(z) = 1$ precisely then).

Is that true?  In that case, the order would be one, correct?

Comment: I think you made a sign mistake. The function $\frac{\exp(z)-1}z$ is known as the first exponential $\varphi$-function. It holds $\varphi_1(z) = \int_0^1e^{(1-\theta)z}\,d\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to recognize the power series in the denominator. From your manipulations, it's evident that $z=0$ is a removable singularity. (You have a quotient of analytic functions, and the denominator doesn't vanish at $z=0$.)

You should note that your function has other singularities as well: the equation $e^z = 1$ has more solutions than $z=0$ (namely $z = 2\pi i k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$).